# Automated import csv - ftp or email?

Tags: php, mysql, email, csv, ftp

My primary question: is there a reason to choose one over the other as a file location to automate update of MySQL - FTP or email?

I will have a small csv file (1 line) and a couple image files that are generated remotely and can be either sent to a FTP site or to an email account.  From there I need the csv file to be updated into the MySQL DB and that data will then be immediately reflected on a website.  This will need to happen twice an hour.

I have reviewed Stack and other online resources.  It seems that via ftp may be more straightforward and require less knowledge (I'm just a plebeian!), and this 
[Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385418/import-csv-file-from-external-ftp-site) seems to get me most of the way there.

A secondary question is, do I have the basic order of events correct:

- Create a cron that calls the ftp or email on schedule
- PHP script that will access and read the csv file
- PHP opens the DB and updates the table and deletes file from ftp or email
- PHP script in HTML that looks to update website

Thank you for viewing and for any assistance you can offer!

Comment: I'd better do it with e-mail =)

Comment: Any reason for your choice or just a preference?  It seemed a lot more to sort out with IMAP, POP, and whatever protocols to have to understand!

Comment: If script is running on the ftp site, or has direct file path access to the file. That would be the easiest solution. Otherwise you will need code or utility to pull the file from FTP or email. FTP will probably be easier.

Comment: @Snacks it is no more complicated then ftp. But for a safety, if encription is on, mail is better.

Answer (score 2):

I'd definitely go with FTP in this case, email would just add a lot of unnecessary complexity.

FTP:

- the import script reads the csv from the disk and you're good (assuming the import script runs on the server where the file has been uploaded)

email:

- the import script has to use pop3/imap libraries and deal with attachment decoding to even get to the file content
- much more bandwith is used (attachments need to be MIME encoded , especially with images this can add a significant amount)
- you need to deal with many more error cases (delayed messages, bounced messages, lost-in-spamquarantine-messages, ...)

as for your secondary question: sounds about right to me, although I don't get what you mean by "PHP script in HTML that looks to update website ". if you have a dynamic website (eg. written in PHP) that checks the database on every request this step sounds unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks Gryphius!  I will try to get something working using the code on the Stack Question I posted above. I'm sure I will have plenty more questions soon...unfortunately...                Regarding your last comment, it is just my lack of knowledge that didn't let me convey that properly.  I meant that the updating of data once in the DB would be done from the website side code (PHP dynamic site), therefore not needed to be included in this script. and